# How to delete the highest value in a group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to delete the highest value from a group.  Given this data:

group_table

```
group_id | st_area
---------------
1        |  20
1        |  30
2        |   1
2        |   1
2        | 200
```

I'd like to remove the second and fifth rows.  I know how to select the highest from each group:

```
SELECT max(area) FROM group_table GROUP BY group_id
```

I can't figure out how to formulate a delete statement that will accept that as a subquery, though.  When I try `delete from group_table where st_area = max(st_area);`

I get an error: `aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause`.

One thing I have learned pretty quickly on SO is that I'm not a terribly good communicator.  If what I'm asking is unclear & you're feeling patient, I'll certainly try to clarify.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a primary key? If not, what do you want to do if there are two MAX rows (e.g. in your example, (1,30) is duplicated)

Comment: No, I don't have a primary key, but it's a temp table and I'm amenable to adding one.  The st_area column is gonna be pretty darned close to unique, though, as it's an areal calculation of some decimal degrees stuff.  It's like 10 digits long.  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have some primary key in your table? According to your specification, you don't.

In this case:

```
DELETE 
  FROM group_table 
  WHERE (group_id, st_area) 
    IN (SELECT group_id, MAX(st_area) FROM group_table GROUP BY group_id);
```

But if you have TWO maximum-value rows, it will delete both.

If in this case you want to delete just one, you should add an id column for the selection:

```
DELETE 
  FROM group_table
  WHERE (id) 
    IN (
      SELECT MAX(id) FROM group_table 
        WHERE (group_id, st_area) 
          IN ( SELECT group_id, MAX(st_area) 
                 FROM group_table 
                 GROUP BY group_id) 
        GROUP BY group_id;
```

);

So you are selecting the maximum id for every maximum st_area for every group id.

In case you have a structure like this:

```
id | gid | area
 1    1     2
 2    1     1
 3    1     2
```

the first query will delete rows 1 and 3, and the second query just 3.

Comment: Your first example works like a charm for me.  Thank you.  

I'm confused about your second example, though.  I don't see any reference to st_area, so I'm not sure how it's going to remove the highest value?